# How to send an email with C++

Tags: c++, email

I'm making a program that supports email functionality within a web browser. I want it to be able to email people and I'm trying to find out how I can accomplish this using C++. Could someone please help?

Comment: Typos, no proper sentences, and asking people to google for you. I google for those who put down some effort.

Comment: @gnud- he's 15, so give him a break ;)

Comment: @gnud - you have the power to edit, please help him express his question more clearly.

Comment: +1 to cancel out these negatives. Having a good list of information on sending email using C++ wouldn't be a detriment to this site.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install an SMTP server (supposing you are on windows), or use sendmail if on linux. If you do not wish to install an SMTP server, you can use an external one as specified in some [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CSMTPConnection2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are your best bet. Your best resource for sockets in C and C++ is: 
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

For an implementation try here: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=300530

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use a library that lets you use an SMTP server (Simple mail transfer protocol). What platform are you developing this for?

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could always write the mail to a file and try using [system(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to invoke [mail(1)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mail/).

> $ mail -s 'OMG!' mybff@example.com < mymailfile

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, I have used [Dundas Ultimate TCP/IP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateTCPIP.aspx) with great results.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried sending email [with CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplesmtp.html) and [with libesmtp](http://www.stafford.uklinux.net/libesmtp/api.html).
Both are good, although I like CURL more because it can work asynchronously.
Also, I have [a header-only curl wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/libglim/source/browse/trunk/curl.hpp). Sending email with it is as simple as:

```
long rc = Curl().send ("Subject: subject\r\n\r\n" "text\r\n") .smtp ("from", "to") .go().status();
if (rc != 250) std::cerr << "Error sending email: " << rc << std::endl;
```